# How to modify index behavior when pivoting dataframe in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, time-series

I'm working with futures timeseries where the trading day starts at 17:00:00 CT and ends at 15:15:00 CT of the next day. To account for this, I make a change in the index, however, when pivoting the dataframe it ignores this change....

Let's look at it with an example:

```
#  Dummy Data
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5000, freq='min')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
df = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns=['ts'])
df_1 = df.resample('5min').last()

# Change index to account for futures hours
df_1.index = pd.to_datetime(df_1.index.values + np.where((df_1.index.time >= datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0))

# Pivoting df_1 and making some formatting changes
df_2 = pd.pivot_table(df_1, index=df_1.index.date, columns=df_1.index.time, values='ts')
df_2.columns = df_2.columns.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%H%M'))
df_2_cols = df_2.columns.tolist()
for i in range(len(df_2_cols)):
    if df_2_cols[i][0] == '0':
        df_2_cols[i] = df_2_cols[i][1:4]
```

After doing all this, the dataframe is in the shape and format I want but the first column, corresponding to the first timestamp of the day is 00:00:00 instead of 17:00:00, as I intended with the index modification.

How can I fix this??

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? With 0.18 `last` requires an `offset` argument.

Answer (score 0):

After pivoting the columns get sorted chronologically. But you can reorder them. Say, the columns are already formatted, so we look for '1700':

```
pos = np.nonzero(df_2.columns == '1700')[0][0]
```

(`np.nonzero` returns a tuple of arrays, hence those double `[0]`). Then

```
new_cols = df_2.columns[pos:].append(df_2.columns[:pos])
df_2 = df_2.reindex(columns = new_cols)
```

Comment: I can't check right now. But does this answer accounts for the fact that the correct value in current row for column '1700' is actually the value that is in the previous row? Because the day starts the day before. I will check when I get home.

Comment: @hernanavella I'm not quite sure what you mean by the word "correct". This reindexing changes only the layout; all the values remain the same (i.e. `df_2.loc[date, time]` is the same before and after `reindex`). Let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: I checked well and your solution just reorders the columns. If you look carefully at the question, you'll see that the issue is that I need to preserve the index as modified by df_1.index = pd.to_datetime(df_1.index.values + np.where((df_1.index.time >= datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0)). The problem is that in the '1700' column the data corresponds to the 'day before' after pivot table basically negates the index modification I made.

Comment: @hernanavella I think the modified index is preserved. (Notice that you change the index of `df_1`.) The value `df_1.loc[datetime.datetime(2011,1,1,17)]` becomes `df_1.loc[datetime.datetime(2011,1,2,17)]` after the change of index, and after pivoting it is `df_2.loc[datetime.date(2011,1,2), '1700']`. And `df_2.loc[datetime.date(2011,1,1), '1700']` is nan. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: It's going to be nan in any case because data starts at 00:00. I think we need to change the dummy data to something fixed rather than random numbers, so we can actually test the difference of your procedure. I tested it on the real data.

Comment: Yes, it's better to test it on a small data frame. And you're right about my code - it's only reordering columns. So if I'm wrong about it, then you need something else. But please try pivoting without modifying  the index. I'm getting then no nan's in the first row, in particular `df_2.loc[datetime.date(2011,1,1), '1700']` is not nan.

Comment: If you get no nan in first day, is even worse. Because there's no real '1700' timestamp for the first day, given that it starts at 0:00. So it mean's your procedure is bringing '1700' from the future. What I want is the opposite, bring the 1700 from the previous day to the current day. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @hernanavella No problem. I think we don't understand each other. A minimal example, say with `rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='6H')`, `ts = pd.Series(range(10), index=rng)`, would certainly help.